# drawing app changing brush color

Tags: java, android, onclick, paint

I'm making an android drawing application.
I would like to make it possible for the user to select a color in the actionbar menu item, colors like green, blue and red. The default color is Black, I did this with the code :

```
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

When the user clicks on the menu item Rood, the brush must be colored RED. How do I make this possible? same with blue and green.

This is my Activity code :

http://pastebin.com/L4Wea5qE

This is my View code :

http://pastebin.com/wPk4kZUX

I hope someone can help me, I'm really stuck

Comment: paint.setColor(Color.RED);

Answer (score 0):

Save the handle to the `SingleTouchEventView` object.

```
SingleTouchEventView mSingleTouchEventView;

public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mSingleTouchEventView = new SingleTouchEventView(this, null);
            setContentView(mSingleTouchEventView);
          }
```

Add a public method in `SingleTouchEventView` class to accept changes in colors.

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
  ...
  public changeColor(int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
      }
...
}
```

Call `changeColor` when the color is selected from Menu.

```
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
...
                if (id == R.id.LijnGroen) {
                        mSingleTouchEventView.changeColor(Color.GREEN);
                        return true;
                }
                if (id == R.id.LijnBlauw) {
                        mSingleTouchEventView.changeColor(Color.BLUE);
                        return true;
                }
                if (id == R.id.LijnRood) {
                        mSingleTouchEventView.changeColor(Color.RED);
                        return true;
                }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the object of `SingleTouchEventView(this, null)`

`SingleTouchEventView stev = new SingleTouchEventView(this, null)`

and then

```
setContentView(stev);
```

and make a function called `setColor(int i)` inside `SingleTouchEventView` class

```
setColor(int i){
 paint.setColor(i);
}
```

and call setColor() function in your `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` function

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.ResetAction) {
                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDun) {
                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDik) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnGroen) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnBlauw) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnRood) {
                       stev.setColor(Color.RED)//for red color

                       return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Or you can make `setColor(int i)` to take the integer argument and pass the integer value in this.

and handle using `switch statement`

like

```
private void setColor(int i){

  switch (i){
     case 1:

         paint.setColor(Color.RED);

     break;

     case 2:

         paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

     break;

     defaul:

         paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

     break;  

  }

}
```

and in your `SingleTouchActivity`

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.ResetAction) {
                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDun) {
                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDik) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnGroen) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnBlauw) {
                    stev.setColor(2)//for blue color
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnRood) {
                       stev.setColor(1)//for red color

                       return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: thank you! it worked , but the problem now is whenever i chose a different color the layout(view) resets, any idea how to fix this?